.NET Framework WindowsIdentity bug with Kerberos where sessions never purge
In C#, I have noticed that when using WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated and passing in a SafeAccessTokenHandle and then disposing of the SafeAccessTokenHandle, when you run C:\\klist sessions, the Kerberos sessions for those disposed SafeAccessTokenHandle's are still listed.
If you have this running as a service, it can be 1000's until they purge. If I comment out the WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated code and dispose of the user token, then use klist sessions, the sessions are cleaned up.
It appears that there is a ref being held in the WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated static methods that prevents those SafeAccessTokenHandle's from being cleaned up.
This is reproducible using this code:
using (var usertoken = ReportSecurityCredentials.FileCopyUserCredentials.LogonUser(ReportSecurityCredentials.LogonTypeSecurity, SimpleImpersonation.LogonProvider.Negotiate))
{
      WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(usertoken, () =>
      {
          //test
      });
}

Command:
klist sessions

The Kerberos session for the impersonated user should not be listed in the sessions

Because your token will be duplicated to support async () => {} without crashing when the task resumes. See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/5d09a8f94c72ca4ef0a9c79eb9c58d06198e3ba9/src/libraries/System.Security.Principal.Windows/src/System/Security/Principal/WindowsIdentity.cs#L753 (the current implementation is partly my fault https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24233, before the Async overrides were added)
